# How to bind user id to socketID in socket.io

Tags: typescript, authentication, sockets, socket.io, nestjs

Good day! I have a task to update user wallet values via a websocket. I understand how to send a message to a specific user, but I have some confusion about certain aspects. Firstly, in the application, there is a custom currency whose price changes. Users have balances in dollars stored in their profiles in the database. If the currency price changes, I need to update the dollar balance for all users. However, I have a problem—I don't understand how to obtain the identifiers of all users who are online. In the socket, they only have a socket identifier. To solve this problem, I wanted to implement socket-based authentication logic and store the user's socket ID in their profile. Can you advise if it's safe to implement registration and login through a socket? Or are there other solutions to identify users via websockets?